# Sharepoint on premise 2016

Tags: 2016

I want to develop dashboard on Sharepoint on premise 2016 which will have list to display count of approved documents,count of uploaded documents and other counts.I have separate lists of approved documents,uploaded documents,feedback documents.I want count of those in other list as per login.I am trying to do it through c# code.Is there any other option to do same or to sync Sharepoint on premise 2016 with sql server?

Comment: not sure what u mean by "count of those in other list as per login". If u don't have to use server specific logic you don't need C#. You can write CSOM Apps / JavaScript code to modify pages and create dashboards. If this is insufficient it could be easier to develop PowerShell code running on server + executed by scheduled task for preparing the needed data for the reporting. So that this is a quite widespread question it's hard to give any more detailed answer.

Comment: I mean by 'count of those in other list as per login' as as per login user,count of his uploaded documents/approved documents will be shown on dashboard list.It is a separate list.Actually I am new to sharepoint.